# Amount based on a prority

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Please feel free to change or suggest me to change my title to better sound on what I am trying to ask.

I have a query that gives the following result:

```
    select 
    Customer.customer_id,
    Transaction.amount

    From Customer inner join Transaction on Customer.customer_id = Transcation.coustomer_id
```

Result:

```
    customer_id| amount

    01456   |50
    01456   |100
    01456   |400  
    01456   |0

    01963   |50
    01963   |100
    01963   |221
    01963   |0
```

Now, I want to add a priority field to give me a priority of 1, 2, or 3. The lower the amount, the higher the priority. Note: I want to replace 0 with text 'Negative'. Ranking amount expect 0.

This is what I want.

```
    customer_id| amount| priority

    01456|    50|   3
    01456|   100|   2
    01456|   400|   1
    01456|     0|   Negative

    01963|    50|   3
    01963|   100|   2
    01963|   221|   1
    01963|     0|   Negative
```

Is this achievable? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` are perfect for this:

```
SELECT c.customer_id,
       t.amount,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY amount desc) priority
FROM Customer c
JOIN [Transaction] t on c.customer_id = t.customer_id
```

The `partition by` resets the numbering on each unique `customer_id`, and the `order by` decides which direction and order to number the rows.

Comment: If the amount is 0 and I want to replace it with the text 'Negative' is it possible to do within the query like 01456|    0|   Negative?

Comment: Is this possible?
    01456|    50|   3
    01456|   100|   2
    01456|   400|   1
   01456|        0|   Negative

Comment: @MilanPk Yeah you can do that: `case when amount = 0 then 'negative' else cast(row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by amount desc) as varchar(100)) end priority`

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select customer_id, amount,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by amount desc) as priority
from t;
```

Comment: Priority order is descending.